# Are declarations of entire responses reusable in swagger-php?

Tags: annotations, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I would love a way to declare some responses that are the same for every endpoint; for example every endpoint will output a `401` if you don't have a proper token, and then there can be another group of endpoints that will all output `404` if you don't have a valid `id` of something in the beginning of your path.

So for almost every method I find myself copy-pasting things such as this:

```
* @OA\Response(response=401, description="If no token..."),
* @OA\Response(response=404, description="If ID of thing invalid..."),
```

The [getting started section](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/Getting-started.html#reusing-annotations-ref) says that reusable responses are supported, but covering only the properties (of successful responses).

There are no examples for the kind of thing i'm looking for, and I also can't get myself to guess anything that would compile.

Something like `@OA\Response(ref="#/components/schemas/Unauthorized")` seems like it should be the way (and the compilation doesn't complain about the presence of the `ref` attribute), but how do i then declare what the `Unauthorized` schema looks like? Because declaring a `@OA\Response` says it only expects the fields: `"ref", "response", "description", "headers", "content", "links", "x"`, none of which can serve as an identifier.

I am using this in conjunction with L5-swagger for Laravel support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a response outside of an operation:

```php
/**
 * @OA\Response(response="Unauthorized", description="If no token...")
 */
```

This will add it to the `#/components/responses/` using the `response=` as value as key.

Then you're able to reuse it later inside an operation:

```php
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *   path="/example",
 *   @OA\Response(response=401, ref="#/components/responses/Unauthorized")
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Shame that the `response=401` still has to explicitly be specified in that second block, I was hoping the response definition would hold that information.. But at least the descriptions don't need to be repeated this way, so it does help 

Comment: FYI this is [in the documentation here](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/cookbook.html#reusing-responses).